# gradle --gui showing specific value of gradle.properties file?

Tags: gradle

I want to show specific environment settings in the gradle gui
using the `description` property.

For example the task `uploadArchives` should show the url where the upload goes to:

```
Upload to maven repository 'file:D:/path/to/my/local/repository'
```

I have done it like this:

```
// Top-level build.gradle 
ext {
    // default value if gradle.properties has no value
    if (!hasProperty("mavenUpload_serverUrl")) mavenUpload_serverUrl = "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
}

task uploadArchives {
    description = "Upload to maven repository '${mavenUpload_serverUrl}'."
    print "Uploading to maven repository '${mavenUpload_serverUrl}'. \n"

    dependsOn { subprojects.uploadArchives }
}
```

This is my local `gradle.properties`

```
# gradle.properties
mavenUpload_serverUrl=file:D:/path/to/my/local/repository
```

I expected to see

```
Upload to maven repository 'file:D:/path/to/my/local/repository'
```

in the gradle gui (started with `gradle --gui`)

but i got

```
Upload to maven repository 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/'
```

When the gradle gui is build `gradle.properties` is not evaluated.

When i execute my task the correct value from `gradle.properties` is used.

```
Uploading to maven repository 'file:D:/path/to/my/local/repository'
```

Any idea how to show the current value in the gradle gui?

I am using gradle 2.13

Comment: Isn't the file URI file://?

Comment: On my win7-64 machine  `file:D:/path/to/my/local/repository` is working . I agree it should be file:// . but this is a different topic